# Caffe install issues, remote server, ld cannot find -<package>

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc, caffe

I'm having issues installing caffe.

I may not have my system setup properly as I had to manually include many libraries in the Makefile.config file. This is a shared server cluster, I do not have sudo priveledges.

Current errors:

```
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
```

I was unable to locate these files looking around. The system uses environmental modules through "module".

These are my current includes in the Makefile.config:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /opt/glog/include /opt/atlas/intel/include /opt/hdf5/intel/openmpi_ib/include /opt//openmpi/intel/ib/include/ /opt/opencv/include/
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /opt/glog/lib
```

Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) intel/2013_sp1.2.144   3) gnutools/2.69          5) hdf5/1.8.14
  2) mvapich2_ib/2.1        4) atlas/3.10.2           6) openmpi_ib/1.8.4

I was wondering if anyone had advice? I'm pretty lost.

EDIT: I switched to MKL and am still having these issues.

Answer (score 1):

append LD_LIBRARY_PATH

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/d/runtime/opencv-2.4.10/lib`

Attention the ':', because the different paths are separated by ':'.